# Order By <collection element's property> in many-to-many association

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have three tables. `Order`, `Location`, `Order_Location` where `Order_Location` is table that holds **many-to-many** relation.

`Order` has `List<Location>`. `Location` has property called `city`. Using HQL (Hibernate 3.6 for Java), I want to get all the locations for a particular order, ordered by the `city`.

In hbm file, `List<Location>` is mapped using **idbag**. Though I got the HQL, the generated SQL query is having join to `Location` and `Order_Location` table twice which I feel is overhead.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT o.locationList FROM Order o
join o.locationList locList  
where o.orderId = 1
order by locList.city desc
```

which translates to something like below

```
select
  order4_.LOC_ID as order1_355_,
  order4_.LOC_CODE as order2_355_,
  order4_.CITY as order3_355_,
  order4_.CITY_LONG_NAME as order4_355_ 
from
   sche.order order0_ 
   inner join
   sche.order_location order1_ 
   on order0_.ORDER_ID=order1_.ORDER_ID 
   inner join
   sche.location order2_ 
   on order1_.LOC_ID=order2_.LOC_ID 
   inner join
   sche.order_location order3_ 
   on order0_.ORDER_ID=order3_.ORDER_ID 
   inner join
   sche.location order4_ 
   on order3_.LOC_ID=order4_.LOC_ID 
 where
   order0_.ORDER_ID=1 
 order by
   order2_.city desc
```

========= EDIT

```
Order.hbm.xml

  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"  

 >
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="collectionorderby.Order" table="ORDER">
        <id name="orderId" type="string">
            <column name="ORDER_ID" length="32" />
            <generator class="uuid" />
        </id>

        <idbag name="locationList" lazy="false" table="ORDER_LOCATION" fetch="select">
            <collection-id column="ORDER_LOCATION_ID" type="string">
                <generator class="uuid" />
            </collection-id>
            <key>
                <column name="ORDER_ID" length="32" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many column="LOC_ID" class="collectionorderby.Location"
                fetch="join" />
        </idbag>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


Location.hbm.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="collectionorderby.Location" table="LOCATION">
        <id name="locId" type="string">
            <column name="LOC_ID" length="50" />
        </id>

        <property name="locCode" type="string">
            <column name="LOC_CODE" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="city" type="string">
            <column name="CITY" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="cityLongName" type="string">
            <column name="CITY_LONG_NAME" length="500" />
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

==== EDIT
Noticed that when we provide `order by`, translated query gets the `select` from first instance of table where as the `order by` is done using the second instance of the table. This will not happen, I suppose, if we avoid the duplicate instance of these tables.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked as expected. The alias `locList` was used in select instead of `o.locationList`

```
SELECT locList  FROM Order o join o.locationList locList  where o.orderId = 1 order by locList.city desc
```